# Overlapped UICollectionView Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

For unknown reasons the cells overlapping like in the pictures below, how can I fix that problem?

[image: First Cell]

[image: Second Cell]

[image: Third Cell]

Answer (score -2):

Solved it

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 200)
}
```